# Multiple useage of QueryPerformanceCounter?

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, time, performancecounter

I am learning threads for about 3 weeks. I now have an exercise to make 3 threads in C and measure the time when the threads created and started in ns. Obviously I use QueryPerformanceCounter for the measuring.

```
...
__int64 Time_Create, Time_Start, freq, start, start2,create, end;
//Time_Create to measure when the thread created. 
//Time_Start to measure the time start.
...
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&start2);
...
for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {...
QueryPerformanceCounter(&create);
//Creating threads
hArray_Of_Thread_Handle[i] = CreateThread(
...
QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);
Time_Create = ((create - start) * 1000000) / freq;
Time_Start = ((end - start2) * 1000000) / freq;
printf("Thread %d created at TC %d ns and started at TS %d ns \n" , i+1 , Time_Create, Time_Start);
}
....
```

And what the output are:

```
Thread 1 created at TC 3 ns and started at TS 0 ns. 
Thread 2 created at TC 1145 ns and started at TS 0 ns.
Thread 3 created at TC 1190 ns and started at TS 0 ns.
```

My Time_Start are always 0, which is wrong.
So I would like to know if it is okay to use multiple QueryPerformanceCounter? Or do I misunderstood the exercise? Or I am implement the wrong way?

Thanks for reading and helps.

EDIT: 
Answer: Change %d to %I64d so that __int64 can be printed.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Sorry. `Time_End` is actually `Time_Start`. When I bring the code up here I worry that naming `Time_End` for starting time is confuse other. In my code all `Time_Start` is `Time_End`. I have just edited the code.

Comment: You can't print an `__int64` with `%d`, that's the format specifier for `int`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried with `%I64d` and it works nicely. Really appreciated your time. It is still weird that some output showed with `%d`.